# Unable to access Result view of LINQ results which implement IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, debugging, watch

I'm trying to use a Visual Studio 2019 debug watch to quickly see the items in multiple collections using LINQ. The LINQ expression goes something like

`baseCollection.Select(o => o.Items)`

Each item in `o.Items` is of a type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`. I want to see the items in each of the results of o.Items, but when I expand the results of the LINQ expression, there is no option for a Results view, only the public and private fields. Adding ,results at the end of the watch doesn't change anything.

Why is that and is there any workaround?

I also made some test classes to reproduce the issue and it happens with these classes as well.

```
class A : IEnumerable<int>
{
    int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<int>)numbers).GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => numbers.GetEnumerator();
}
class B : IEnumerable<A>
{
    A[] array = { new A() };

    public IEnumerator<A> GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<A>)array).GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => array.GetEnumerator();
}
```

The test watch

```
new B().Select(a => a.numbers)
```

In this test I can always expand the numbers array and see its contents, but with the types I'm actually using outside the test it's not an array but something else which I have to rely on its `IEnumerable<T>` implementation.

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69dVM.jpg)

Comment: "I also made some test classes to reproduce the issue" Great! Can you _post_ those here by [edit]ing your question so we have a [mcve]? Also, it might be helpful to show a screenshot of what you mean by "there is no option for a Results view".

Comment: "there is no option for a Results view, only the public and private fields" - what does that mean?

Comment: What IDE are you using? Have you read [ask]?

Comment: Made a small mistake, in the test watch, updated it

Comment: Turns out even if I just make a watch a given array or List it doesn't show the Results View either, only when I use the type of collection in the library I'm using, but not through LINQ. The type that works only implements IEnumerable<> and IEnumerable, just like List<> does.